# Split dataframe into subsets by pairs of columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, subset

I have a wide dataframe with *N* columns. Columns are presented in pairs like this: the first two go together, and so the next two, until the end of the dataframe:

```
  XS0552790049  Unnamed: 5583 XS0628646480  Unnamed: 5585
0   2010-10-22          100.0   2011-05-24         99.711
1   2010-10-25          100.0   2011-05-25         99.685
2   2010-10-26          100.0   2011-05-26        100.125
3   2010-10-27          100.0   2011-05-27         99.893
4   2010-10-28          100.0   2011-05-30         99.792
```

I want to subset this dataframe into *N/2* subsets, each containing a pair of neighbour columns, so for example the first pair would be `["XS0552790049","Unnamed: 5583"]`.

I thought about using a for loop, but I am definitely missing something as it does not generate the subsamples. Perhaps I am indexing wrong.

Here's my attempt: I tried to create a dictionary containing a subsample for every key.

```py
sub = {}
for i in range(0,len(df.columns)+1):
    sub[i] = df.iloc[:,i:i+3]
```

I am pretty new with Python, so any suggestion is welcome.

Columns descriptions, for the record:

- column 1: ISIN 1, sequence of daily dates (issuance to maturity of bond 1)
- column 2: historical data on prices wrt ISIN1
- column 3: ISIN 2, sequence of daily dates (issuance to maturity of bond 2)
- column 4: historical data on prices wrt ISIN2
  and so on.

Comment: Based on your example data, what do you expect the output to be?

Answer (score 0):

Mostly, you just omitted the step in your `range(start, stop, step)` iterator, use step=2.

Then [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) advantageously encase `for` loops in such cases:

```py
dfs = [ df.iloc[:,[i,i+1]] for i in range(0, len(df.columns), 2) ]
```

*(Note that either `[:,[i,i+1]]` or `[:,i:i+2]]` do return the same range and thus may be used with identically.)*

This will return your requested list of pairwise subsets:

```py
dfs
[  XS0552790049  Unnamed: 5583
 0   2010-10-22          100.0
 1   2010-10-25          100.0
 2   2010-10-26          100.0
 3   2010-10-27          100.0
 4   2010-10-28          100.0,
   XS0628646480  Unnamed: 5585
 0   2011-05-24         99.711
 1   2011-05-25         99.685
 2   2011-05-26        100.125
 3   2011-05-27         99.893
 4   2011-05-30         99.792]
```

```py
dfs[0]
  XS0552790049  Unnamed: 5583
0   2010-10-22          100.0
1   2010-10-25          100.0
2   2010-10-26          100.0
3   2010-10-27          100.0
4   2010-10-28          100.0
```

Side notes:

- One should refrain from using `sub` as a variable name, since this is a Python function in the [`re`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) module.
- A list looks more appropriate than a dictionary, unless you mean to specify keys to refer to each pair. Here, you use a simple index, so, a list is enough.
- `df.shape[1]` may replace `len(df.columns)`, since dataframe dimensions are also given by [`df.shape`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shape.html) as a tuple.

Comment: It worked, but with `i+2` instead of `i+1` as upper limit in the range submitted to `iloc`, and without enclosing the slicing interval with square brackets. 
The following code gave me the desired output, to be accessed as list as you suggested:

`dfs = [ df.iloc[:,i:i+2] for i in range(0,len(dt1.columns),2)]`

Thank you again for helping.

Comment: @EmanuelePizzochera Because we split by *pairs*, both solutions work equally: `[:,[i,i+1]]` and `[:,i:i+2]]`. So, it's not "it worked, but...". It's "it also works this way". Do you see the difference and why it's the same? I called both columns indices, while you called a range of indices.

Comment: Hello @EmanuelePizzochera, any feedback after this exchange?